# RSS Aggregator for Craft?

Tags: rss

Curious if anything exists like this for Craft?

http://www.wpexplorer.com/create-rss-news-aggregation-portal-wordpress/

Just looking for something that can look at an RSS feed and post entries to a Craft powered site.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the following plugin could help to import entries from RSS:

[Craft CMS plugin to import entries from XML](https://github.com/clearbold/craftimport)

Answer (score 2):

Until the plugin store becomes an "official thing", the best, most curated list of plugins available for Craft is over at [Straight Up Craft](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins).

I'm not seeing anything that would do exactly what you're looking for, but it wouldn't be a difficult one to write.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the same. Thanks. Was hoping there were some 3rd party addons that maybe were not listed there.